# Undefined offset to the array item getting array from const

Tags: php

I have defined a const with an array.

```
CONST DEFAULT_PRICES = array(30, 20, 10);
```

Now I have used this constant inside in function like below:

```
foreach ($workingDays as $selectedDate) {
    //get the index 
    $index = array_search($selectedDate, $workingDays);

    $price = $basePrice + ($basePrice * self::DEFAULT_PRICES[$index ] / 100);
    $price = sprintf("%.2f", $price);

    $dateArr[$selectedDate] = $basePrice;

}
```

But I am getting error saying Message: Undefined offset: 3

can anybody tell me why?

Comment: array indexes start at 0, so your constant has indexes 0, 1 and 2; not 3. Perhaps you need to subtract 1 from `$index`?

Comment: @Nick then i get Message: Undefined offset: -1

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need more elements in your `DEFAULT_PRICES` array then? You need to check what the actual values of `$index` being produced are and adjust your array to suit.